# How to write onComplete function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to change this line of code?
 I tried to do barcode scanning just from html to get exact data from same as what i got in notepad.

```
$(document).scannerDetection({

    timeBeforeScanTest: 200, // wait for the next character for upto 200ms
    avgTimeByChar: 40, // it's not a barcode if a character takes longer than 100ms
    preventDefault: true,
    endChar: [7],

    $("#userInput").onComplete(function(){ //i got error here.. why?
    validScan = true;

    alert("Job Start");
    var text = $(this).text();
    var barcode = text.substring(1,4);
    $('input[type="text"]').val(barcode);
    )};
    //  } // main callback function ,
    //,
    //onError: function(string) {

    //$('#userInput').val ($('#userInput').val()  + string);

    //}

});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    <p><strong> Scan BarCode : </strong></p>
    <input id="userInput" type="text" autofocus readonly/><br/><br/><br/>

    <p><strong> BarCode : </strong></p>
    <p> <input type="text" readonly/></p><br/><br/><br/>

    <p><strong> Zone : </strong></p>
    <p> <input id="zone" type="text" readonly/></p><br/><br/><br/>  

</body>
</html>`
```

i got error in line 16... the way i wrote onComplete function is false.

Comment: looks like you didn't close your function properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jay suggested your function is not closed properly and try to read the below source on how to use oncomplete

https://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-scannerdetection-tutorial.html

```
$("#userInput").onComplete(function(){ //i got error here.. why?
    validScan = true;

    alert("Job Start");
    var text = $(this).text();
    var barcode = text.substring(1,4);
    $('input[type="text"]').val(barcode);
 });


<script type="text/javascript" src="your_path/jquery.scannerdetection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).scannerDetection({
    timeBeforeScanTest: 200, // wait for the next character for upto 200ms
    startChar: [120], // Prefix character for the cabled scanner (OPL6845R)
    endChar: [13], // be sure the scan is complete if key 13 (enter) is detected
    avgTimeByChar: 40, // it's not a barcode if a character takes longer than 40ms
    onComplete: function(barcode, qty){ ... } // main callback function 
});
</script>
```